# JavaScript Table.Rowd Collection Undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert a row into a table by cloning a row and replace it's values from a model. I'm open to doing this some other way. I'm very new to JavaScript and this code is from an example I found.

```
function createNewRow(model)
{
    // Make a copy of the first row
    var table = document.getElementById('divData');
    var new_row = table.rows[1].cloneNode(true);        // <======  Error occurs here. The Table exists, the rows collection does not.
    var len = table.rows.length;
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

    // Copy the model's data to the new row
    new_row.cells[1].value = model.SiteId;
    new_row.cells[2].value = model.InstrumentId;
    new_row.cells[3].value = model.TowerLocation;
    new_row.cells[4].value = model.BayLocation;
    new_row.cells[5].value = model.BaySerialNo;
    new_row.cells[6].value = model.BayStatus;
    new_row.cells[7].value = model.AccessionId;
    new_row.cells[8].value = model.Result;
    new_row.cells[9].value = model.AssayName;
    new_row.cells[10].value = model.Started;
    new_row.cells[11].value = model.Completed;
    new_row.cells[12].value = model.TestSummary;

    // Add the new row to the table
    table.appendChild(new_row);
}
```

**[UPDATE] - Added table code**

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    <div id="divData">
        @{
            var grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 10, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "divData", canPage: true);

            @grid.GetHtml(
            tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
            headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
            footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
            alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
            selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
            rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            columns:
            grid.Columns
            (
                grid.Column(columnName: "RowId", header: "Row Id", format: @<text><span data-row-id="@item.RowId">@item.RowId</span></text>),
                grid.Column(columnName: "SiteId", header: "Site Id", format: @<text><span class="x-SiteId">@item.SiteId</span></text>),
            ))
        }
    </div>
}
```

The table does exist, and there are rows in the table, yet on the line I indicated above I get "Cannot read property '1' of undefined"

When I do `console.log(table.Rows)` I get 'undefined'.

Anyone see what's wrong?

Thank you

Comment: There's a capitalization difference in your Rs maybe a typo? You can also just iterate the NodeList.children

Comment: If you `console.log(table)` what do you get? It appears as though you are not getting your table correctly.

Comment: @lixus, console.log(table) shows the table. I can see the rows of data in it

Comment: @SterlingArcher I'm sorry I don't understand. What is Rs? Where is the capitalization problem?

Comment: Is your `divData` a `<div>` element or the actual table? If it's the first one that's why you are getting the error

Comment: @Lixus It's a<div>. I updated my post with the table code

Comment: You have to target the `<table>` tag, not the `<div>`, because `<div>` doesn't have a property `.rows` like `<table>` does

Comment: @Lixus OK, but I don't understand how. I don't have a <table> tag. I'm using a WebGrid. See my table code I added in my posting. Can you show me how to do this? Thanks

Comment: @Lixus I figured it out. I set the ID on the web grid, then used that to get the table ref. Thank you